# How can I get the file-name list of a directory from hdfs in pyspark?

Tags: file, path, directory, pyspark, hdfs

I have a directory in hdfs wich contains many files. I know the path of the directory and I am trying to get a list of those filenames the directory contains. How could I do it?

If I have a directory as follows:

```
+dir/
    +f1
    +f2
    +fN
```

I want to get a list as follows:

```
[f1, f2, fN]
```

Comment: None of the provided answers satisfied you?

Answer (score 18):

You can use HDFS (or any other compatible Hadoop filesystem) API in pyspark with a little py4j magic. To list files from a specific directory use:

```
path = "/here/is/my/dir/"
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
list_status = fs.listStatus(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path))
result = [file.getPath().getName() for file in list_status]
```

The elements of `list_status` collection are of type [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html). With this API you can get files metadata, such as information if it's directory, mode, owner, group, acls and use these information to filter out unwanted files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality in Pyspark for this (**EDIT**: see answer by Mariusz and UPDATE at the end) - this functionality is provided in the Python package [pywebhdfs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywebhdfs) (simply install by `pip install pywebhdfs`):

```py
from pywebhdfs.webhdfs import PyWebHdfsClient
from pprint import pprint

hdfs = PyWebHdfsClient(host='192.10.10.73',port='50070', user_name='ctsats')  # your Namenode IP & username here
my_dir = 'user/ctsats'
pprint(hdfs.list_dir(my_dir))
```

The result is a (rather long) Python dictionary (not shown) - experiment a little to get a feeling. You can parse it to get the names and types (file/directory) as follows:

```py
data = hdfs.list_dir(my_dir)
dd = [[x["pathSuffix"], x["type"]] for x in data["FileStatuses"]["FileStatus"]]
dd
# [[u'.Trash', u'DIRECTORY'], [u'.sparkStaging', u'DIRECTORY'], [u'checkpoint', u'DIRECTORY'], [u'datathon', u'DIRECTORY'], [u'ms-spark', u'DIRECTORY'], [u'projects', u'DIRECTORY'], [u'recsys', u'DIRECTORY'], [u'sparklyr', u'DIRECTORY'], [u'test.data', u'FILE'], [u'word2vec', u'DIRECTORY']]
```

From here, a simple list comprehension should do the job - for example, in my case where I have both files & directories present, here is how I coud keep only the directories:

```py
sub_dirs = [x[0] for x in dd if x[1]=='DIRECTORY']
sub_dirs
# [u'.Trash', u'.sparkStaging', u'checkpoint', u'datathon', u'ms-spark', u'projects', u'recsys', u'sparklyr', u'word2vec']
```

For comparison, here is the actual listing of the same directory:

```sh
[ctsats@dev-hd-01 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls
Found 10 items
drwx------   - ctsats supergroup          0 2016-06-08 13:31 .Trash
drwxr-xr-x   - ctsats supergroup          0 2016-12-15 20:18 .sparkStaging
drwxr-xr-x   - ctsats supergroup          0 2016-06-23 13:23 checkpoint
drwxr-xr-x   - ctsats supergroup          0 2016-02-03 15:40 datathon
drwxr-xr-x   - ctsats supergroup          0 2016-04-25 10:56 ms-spark
drwxr-xr-x   - ctsats supergroup          0 2016-06-30 15:51 projects
drwxr-xr-x   - ctsats supergroup          0 2016-04-14 18:55 recsys
drwxr-xr-x   - ctsats supergroup          0 2016-11-07 12:46 sparklyr
-rw-r--r--   3 ctsats supergroup         90 2016-02-03 16:55 test.data
drwxr-xr-x   - ctsats supergroup          0 2016-12-15 20:18 word2vec
```

The WebHDFS service in your Hadoop cluster must be enabled, i.e. your `hdfs-site.xml` file must include the following entry:

```xml
<property>
    <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

**UPDATE** (after Mariusz's answer): Here is an adaptation of Mariusz's answer for Spark 1.6 (you need to replace `spark` with `sc`) in my example:

```py
path="/user/ctsats"
fs = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
list_status = fs.listStatus(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path))
result = [file.getPath().getName() for file in list_status]
result
# [u'.Trash', u'.sparkStaging', u'checkpoint', u'datathon', u'ms-spark', u'projects', u'recsys', u'sparklyr', u'test.data', u'word2vec']
```

The issue here is that *both files and subfolders* are returned, without any means for distinction between them. The `pywebhdfs` solution, as demonstrated, does not suffer from this...

I guess there are ways to overcome this, but you will have to dig into the py4j API - despite the deceiving appearence, `list_status` is *not* a Python list:

```py
list_status
# JavaObject id=o40
```

Answer (score 0):

for python 3 using subprocess library:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
hdfs_path = '/path/to/the/designated/folder'
process = Popen(f'hdfs dfs -ls -h {hdfs_path}', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
list_of_file_names = [fn.split(' ')[-1].split('/')[-1] for fn in std_out.decode().readlines()[1:]][:-1]
list_of_file_names_with_full_address = [fn.split(' ')[-1] for fn in std_out.decode().readlines()[1:]][:-1]
```